# initiating multiprocesses Pool in a for loop in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

So i wrote a function that collects a list of files in a directory. These are cut in to sizes of 4 and fed to a multiprocess pool using a for loop. Below is the code for clairity.

```
def Main():

    allft_files = listdir(path_allft)
    ncores = cpu_count()

    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    for i in range(0, len(allft_files ), ncores):

        chuncks = [allft_files[x:x + 1] for x in range(i, i+4, 1)]
        pool_processes = Pool(processes=ncores)
        pool_processes.map(filter_allft, chuncks)
```

My question is if all processes are completed and joined before the next iteration starts. Or does the script jump to the next iteration in the for loop when one of the processes finishes. Because processing time for each proces is slightly different. Im not really sure how pool works in that aspect.

Comment: Don't just indent the first line and then paste.  Paste and then use the format as code button ("{}").

Comment: Your question "if all processes are completed and joined before next iterations starts" isn't a complete sentence.  Maybe you can try to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Edited question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) (emphasis mine):

> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). **It blocks until the result is ready**.

The result cannot be ready until each element is ready.  Each element will only be ready after the work in the process pool has completed.  Therefore, the last line of your loop:

```
pool_processes.map(filter_allft, chuncks)
```

will not finish until `filter_allft` has been applied to every element of `chuncks`.  Only once this has happened will execution proceed to the next iteration of the loop.

*However*, there is no code in your example which *explicitly* cleans up the process pool (terminates its processes or joins them).  Therefore, they will only be terminated when the garbage collector collects the pool.  It is most likely that this will happen on the *next* iteration of the loop when a new pool replaces the old one in the `pool_processes` variable.

So while the work will all have been completed before the next iteration begins, the processes will not be cleaned up until after the next iteration begins.  If the pool is cleaned up by the reference counting system, its processes will at least be terminated before the next iteration creates any *more* processes.  If you have to rely on the cycle detector, you will probably have multiple active pools concurrently.

To avoid this, you could add an explicit:

```
pool_processes.terminate()
pool_processes.join()
```

to the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing` documentation drives me crazy. Pools do work and return results. The `map` function fans out a sequence of tasks and waits for all of the tasks to complete so that it can assemble and return all of the results. You'd think the docs would mention that! So, as you suspect, the `map` has to completely finish before you start the next data set.

Your code has a bug - you setup a new Pool in each iteration which simply abandons the old Pool and is needlessly expensive. As a minimum, move the pool creation out of the `for`.

It sounds like you'd benefit from using one of the async calls. The `map` or `apply` call returns immediately with an `ApplyResult` object you can use to wait for the result. Here are a couple of examples for whether you care about the result.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import contextlib

def worker(i,j):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    print('done', i, j)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # The Pool context manager terminates the pool (killing workers)
    # but we just want to close (letting workers finish) and join.
    with contextlib.closing(mp.Pool(8)) as pool:
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(20):
                pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,j))
    pool.join()

    print("\nIf you want to process the results\n")
    results = []

    with contextlib.closing(mp.Pool(8)) as pool:
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(20):
                results.append(pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,j)))
    for result in results:
        result.get()
    pool.join()
```